# AngularJS disable directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the `editable-text` directive from the `xeditable` module for AngularJS. Is there a way to disable the directive for the entire page?

I thought about using replacing editable-text with `{{variable}}`, where `variable="editable-text"` to enable and `variable="somethingElse"` to disable. However, this produces meaningless attributes in the html.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't have a scope variable on the page controller, use ng-hide='booleanVar' on the directive tag and then toggle the booleanVar to show or hide?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to remove directive with another directive. For this, new directive should have higher priority than the one being removed, then in compilation state you search for elements with required directive and remove tag/class/element wholetogether. Here's a very simple realisation of this:

```
.directive("disableDirective", function () {
    function compile (el, attr) {
        var hasDirective = el[0].querySelectorAll("["+attr.disableDirective+"]");

        [].forEach.call(hasDirective, function (el) {
            el.removeAttribute(attr.disableDirective);
        });
    }

    return {
        priority: 100000,
        compile: compile
    };
})
```

In the following HTML DIV will be visible, thanks to our directive:

```
<body disable-directive="ng-hide">
  <div ng-hide="true">Hidden</div>
</body>
```

You'll have to set `disable-directive="editable-text"` for the page.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zitup/2/).

Comment: It does not work for dynamically created nodes. http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/cxvxapme/

Comment: If you find solution, do not hesitate to post it as another answer. I didn't claim that it will handle all imaginable scenarios.

Comment: I have no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to turn off this directive across all app forever, I know two ways:

1. Create decorator for this directive and just set the `compile` function to empty function e.g. to `angular.noop`. Check this stuff for more info:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator .
2. Or you can also create directive with the same name and restrictions (A|E|C|M), but with higher priority and `terminal` property setted to `true`. But you should always keep in mind that this directive will turn off all directives with lower priority on the same element. (so this solution looks like antipattern for me)

Comment: Thanks this really helped. Here is an example/code for this answer http://pastebin.com/raw/mHEn1s9D

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can remove the restrict field using a decorator. this would disable the directive. Here is an example using ng-show

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

//disable ng-show
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('ngShowDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.restrict = ""; 
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```