# manually removing or disabling directive on specific page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive called MenuBarDirective that is on each page.  Within that MenuBarDirective, I have another directive, TrackerDirective to track mouse movement, clicks, etc.  On specific pages within the app, I want to disable the TrackerDirective.  Is there an easy way to dynamically remove or disable a my TrackerDirective that lives inside MenuBarDirective in a completely different page?

Comment: May be your question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744080/angularjs-disable-directive

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

1. pass a variable from the parent directive [e.g. 'doTrack' as a boolean] and have the child directive turn on/off accordingly
2. open a method in the parent directive as an API for the child directive to ask whether to track or not...